# When I log in, I return to the login page again, despite the fact that the database contains values ​well

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller

```
--view--

--login--

<body>
  <form action="/login" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</body>

--main--

<body>
    <button><a href="login">let's login</a></button>
    <button><a href="join">let's join</a></button>
</body>
```

```
-- controller -- 
@PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@Validated LoginRequestDto dto, HttpSession session) {
        Optional<Member> findMember = memberService.findMemberByEmail(dto.getEmail());
        if (findMember.isPresent()) {
            Member member = findMember.get();
            if (member.getPassword().equals(dto.getPassword())) {
                session.setAttribute("userId", dto.getEmail());
                return "redirect:/main";
            } else {
                return "redirect:/login";
            }
        } else {
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
    }
```

```
-- security --

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/main").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/join").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/join").permitAll()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login-process")
                .successHandler(((request, response, authentication) -> {response.sendRedirect("/");}))
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll();

        return http.build();
```

When I log in, I return to the login page again, despite the fact that the database contains values ​​well.

It seems that Spring Security settings are wrong, but it is difficult to solve because there is not much information about Spring Boot 3.0 or higher.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `login` method and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is this error not directly related to not able to establish a connection to your database? Just double check that your Config files are correctly set, your dbs name, username and password as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).